# Disable facebook connect button in jquery dialog form popup

Tags: php, jquery, facebook, drupal

In my site,i am using a facebbok api.

Whenever user clicks the login a popup will be shown ,and can login through email or facebook connect.
The popup will be still there,after the first click,until the page loads.

I want only the facebook connect button in the popup to disable,after the first click.

**For the popup i am using :**

`$(".msg").fancybox({
             showCloseButton: false,
             padding: 0,
             margin: 0

```
     }).trigger('click'); `


  **and for checking facebook login:**


   if (fb) {        
    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        if ('connected' == response.status) {       
          reload(url, param);  --------->to reload to the mentioned page                         

        }
        return false;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

An example at http://jsfiddle.net/ would be good in this case because I cannot really help you else. You want to disable some kind of Element inside a Popup right?

example: Your Button you want to disable is an  with the class 'xy'

```
$('input.xy').hide();
```

Comment: i dont think this will work..as for the fb login i am using                                                    `<fb:login-button scope="<?=FB_PERMISSIONS?>" v="2" onlogin="reload_page('<?=$page?>','<?=$param?>');" >Login</fb:login-button>`

Comment: Take a look at the HTML output and look there for the element